# Sublime Text 3 plugin: SublimeLinter

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I am using Sublime Text 3. Recently I uninstall my sublimelinter plugin and reinstall it in order to get the latest version. The previous sublimelinter version works fine.

I know in the new version of sublimelinter, all the linters now have to be installed separately.

1) So I did install sublimelinter first, however when I browse for the package installed, I couldn't see sublimelinter installed? **(1st problem)**

2) Then I went ahead and install sublimelinter-csslint through node.js and also within sublime text. When I browse for the package, it is installed.

3) I intentionally made a mistake in my CSS, not having " ; " at the end. But csslint isn't picking up the error? So I will assume the installation failed. **(2nd problem)**

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem so I went to the cmd line and tried 
`csslint style.css` 
it complained 
`/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

so I found @rosamunda answer at [Cannot install NodeJs: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320901/cannot-install-nodejs-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory)

this worked for me :-)

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

and then restart sublime text.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem silly, but did you restart sublime after installing the main package?

Comment: Yes I did and the problems remain.

Answer (score 0):

I can't do it with Package Control.
I have to install through the source. Not ideal, in fact strongly discourage but no choice.