# Cannot install NodeJs: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gruntjs, npm-install, node-modules

I'm trying to install nodeJs into my Ubuntu 14.04 in order to use GruntJs.

I've read about [Ubuntu different way](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) of doing it ([issues?](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2241)), so this is what I've done in order to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install npm

sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Typing grunt after that I've got the error:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

So, I've tried:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

sudo apt-get update
```

And trying again, and still getting the error, I've tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I've got this message:

```
nodejs is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
```

I did try a cleanup just in case:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

But nope, the error is still there: when I type grunt I still get `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

What should I do?

Comment: This problem does not occur with Ubuntu 20.04. `sudo apt-file find /usr/bin/node` lists `nodejs: /usr/bin/node`. That is, installing the `nodejs` package installs the expected `node` executable program.

Answer (score 869, accepted):

Doing a symlink solves the issue:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

(My thanks and +1 vote to [bodokaiser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20890795/1983854)).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy` creates this link too, see description at https://packages.debian.org/sid/nodejs-legacy

Comment: This fix is seriously a lifesaver. Especially, if you are following the fixing permissions guide here https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: thanks, this is help me to solved my problem on docker too https://github.com/yussan/docker-nodejs-boilerplate/tree/master/multiple-apps

Comment: I added it to `/usr/local/bin` just so I remember it's a custom symlink.

Comment: when i run on mac - sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
 it says sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: Further information about the name conflict (resolution): https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2012/07/msg00002.html

Comment: is was `ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs` for me... just ran `which node` to find the proper place.

Comment: ln: /usr/bin/node: Operation not permitted

Comment: @rd_ Obviously, you are editing the /usr/bin directory. Only root can do that.

Comment: You should use `which node` so you get the correct path to your node. So the command would be `ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node`

Comment: ln: /usr/bin/node: Operation not permitted even with sudo. OSX.

Comment: Doesnt work here because `/usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory` even though `Package 1:npm-3.10.10-1.6.17.1.1.el7.x86_64 already installed`

Comment: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/node': File exists`

Answer (score 129):

The issue is not with the version of node. Instead, it is the way NodeJS is installed by default in Ubuntu. When running a Node application in Ubuntu you have to run `nodejs something.js` instead of `node something.js`

So the application name called in the terminal is `nodejs` and not `node`. This is why there is a need for a symlink to simply forward all the commands received as `node` to `nodejs`.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: Thanks! Same "issue" on Fedora if you choose to install the nodejs20 package from (binary is named node-20 here) dnf... I had already set an alias for it in zsh (node = node-20) but that was not sufficient for npm to understand but the symlink sure does the trick :) Not sure why the heck the symlink is not created by the package itself..

Answer (score 95):

if you are using `nvm` node version manager, use this command to create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s "$(which npm)" /usr/bin/npm
```

- The first command creates a symlink for `node`
- The second command creates a symlink for `npm`

Comment: I prefer `/usr/local/bin/node` instead

Comment: This works, but if you intend to use nvm to actual manage different versions then you have to repeat this every time you nvm to a different version.

Comment: This work, I installed node using nvm, and have problem with running laravel-echo-server which run on node. You saved me after 2 hours. thanks

Comment: This worked. thanks 
i was getting error `/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory` when i run git commit.

Comment: sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/local/bin/node
sudo ln -s "$(which npm)" /usr/local/bin/npm

These commands will be favorable as doing symlinks in /usr/bin folders are not allowed directly for root users also. will have to disable csrutil, which is not a good practice

Answer (score 70):

I think you should upgrade lastest node version

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Comment: Just a tip; indent your lines of code by 4 spaces ;) also, `n` is not a command that's associate with Node.JS.

Comment: @David based on the package description on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n): "Interactively Manage All Your Node Versions"

Comment: Solved the problem for me

Comment: i copied a `laravel` project from `windows` machine to `ubuntu 16.04` and `laravel mix` had problem with `npm run watch` AND this solution worked for me and now problem gone

Comment: It should be mentioned here that `n` is a 3rd-party _package manager_ for NodeJS, and therefore is **not** installing the "lastest [sic] node version".

Answer (score 29):

if you are able to access node on ubuntu terminal using nodejs command,then this problem can be simply solved using
-creating a symbolic link of nodejs and node using

`ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

and this may solve the problem

Answer (score 26):

In my case, [installing nodejs-legacy](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) solved the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Answer (score 11):

Just do

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

And it will start working.

Answer (score 10):

If you already have nodejs installed (check with `which nodejs`) and don't want to install another package, you can, as root:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 99
```

Comment: This is the proper Debian way.

Comment: this worked for me. ubuntu 20,node 10 npm 8

Answer (score 9):

I've found this is often a misnaming error, if you install from a package manager you bin may be called nodejs so you just need to symlink it like so

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: Instead of adding a negative feedback, let me know here in the comment what is wrong, so I can help you with that. Since there is nothing wrong in creating a symlink especially if it helps you manage things better.

Comment: I for my self prefer this approach. It's clean.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on how you installed your node, most of the time it might not be in /usr/bin/, in my own case it was I used nvm to install so my node was in ./nvm/versions.

Using this command `which node` I found out the path, but to make the work easier you can run this command.

```
nodepath=$(which node); sudo ln -s $nodepath /usr/bin/node
```

the above command will get the location of your node and create a link for you.

Answer (score 6):

When I was using gulp i got this error.

```
~$ gulp
```

/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

This was removed by executing following command you have to keep in mind that /usr/bin directory has all permissions.

```
~$ ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

this works for me..

Comment: I had the same issue, but the solution didnt worked. I check whether node is installed or not using "node -v" command, and found it missing. It must be because I upgraded from 10.04 to ubuntu 20.04 recently.

Answer (score 6):

There are two solutions to this:

a) Set your PATH variable to include "/usr/local/bin"

`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"`

b) Create a symlink to "/usr/bin" which is already in your PATH

`ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Follow these commands to fix the problem.

In a terminal:

1. Clean the entire NPM cache:

   ```
   $ sudo npm cache clean -f
   ```
2. ```
   sudo npm install -g n
   ```
3. Install the latest stable version of Node.js:

   ```
   sudo n stable
   ```

Now the latest version of Node.js was installed. Check the version using:

```
node -v
```

Comment: Worked! Great..

Answer (score 6):

In case it's installed by using snap,

```
sudo ln -sfn /snap/node/current/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

Answer (score 4):

While `ln -s` is the obvious easiest fix, a piece of explanation:

> Because of a conflict with another package, the executable from the
>   Ubuntu repositories is called nodejs instead of node. Keep this in
>   mind as you are running software.

This advice comes up, when installing `sudo apt-get install nodejs`.

So some other known tool (I don't know what it does. While being known to ubuntu repositories, it is not installed by default in 16.04) occupies that namespace.

Would have been nice, if Ubuntu had offered an advice how to fix this 'cleanly', if not by doing by hand what otherwise the package would do. (a collision remains a collision... if+when it would occur)

Comment: @tom-hale answer is the Ubuntu way for this.  You use alternatives to specify the correct node

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin" npm install -g <package-name>
```

Answer (score 2):

For my case link **did** **NOT** **work** as follow

> ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

But you can open /usr/local/bin/lessc as root, and change the first line from node to nodejs.

> -#!/usr/bin/env node
>
> +#!/usr/bin/env nodejs

Answer (score 1):

it's been 7 years ago and the problems still relevant and occurred.

Oke here my problem, it's similar but not exactly the same.

When I call this command from Jenkins

ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "pm2 restart app"

then error /usr/bin/env Node No Such file or directory

Then here my solution:

on server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

It relink /usr/bin/node

First:
I remove the existing one with command "rm -f /usr/bin/node"

Second:
I create new link with this command
"ln -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.4/bin/node /usr/bin/node"

Node version it's depends on your installation. May it help.

THe bottom line for this error is link of node.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the command or file name `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` by this command

Answer (score 0):

For me the accepted answer did not yet work. I started off as suggested here:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

After doing this I was getting the following error:

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
>         let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
>         ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class)
>   not yet supported outside strict mode
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
>       at startup (node.js:136:18)
>       at node.js:966:3

The solution was to download the most recent version of node from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ .

Then I did:

```
sudo tar -xf node-v10.15.0-linux-x64.tar.xz --directory /usr/local --strip-components 1
```

Now the update was finally successful: `npm -v` changed from 3.2.1 to 6.4.1

Answer (score 0):

For those who have installed NodeJS with [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating).

If like me you have installed, uninstalled, reinstalled some versions you simply need to do this :

> nvm use v14.21.1

Or whatever version you are using.

This will recreate the links to `node` and `npm` commands that where lost during your 'cleanup' :D

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo nautilus
```

Open file manager as admin. Go to /usr/bin and search node.That might have been broken link, so delete it. Now try installing your package.
It might work -worked for me