# Using NSTask to execute ionic build commands - launch path not accessible

Tags: objective-c, node.js, macos, ionic-framework, nstask

I'm working with Ionic which has a command line interface. I would like to create a small Mac app that helps to execute certain commands.

In the terminal I `cd Users/me/Desktop/Repos/ionic-project/myApp`
After changing I would e.g. `ionic run`

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc]init];

task.launchPath = @"/bin/bash";
task.currentDirectoryPath = @"cd Users/me/Desktop/Repos/ionic-tryouts/myApp";
task.arguments = @[@"ionic run"];

[task launch];
```

But this gives me 'working directory doesn't exist.'
I've already read quite some threads here on SO. Whats my mistake?

---

EDIT:

Thanks Christik for the detailed answer. I now have this code:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc]init];
task.launchPath = @"/usr/local/bin/ionic";
task.currentDirectoryPath = @"/Users/me/ionic-tryouts/myApp";
task.arguments = @[@"run"];

[task launch];
```

Now I get the following error: env: node: `No such file or directory`. I guess this comes from a problem, that node.js isn't found (ionic is build on top of node). I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320901/cannot-install-nodejs-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory) issue - a missing symlink with the right name might be the cause. But setting the symlink for node didn't help. Any ideas?

---

EDIT2:
I gave Christik the correct answer, even though I couldn't finally get it to work. I'm still investigation. Maybe it's the node installation thats wrong.

---

EDIT3:
I saw some posts that mentioned that it might be better, if node was re-installed by homebrew since homebrew installs it without sudo. Short comment: didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `bash` to launch `ionic`, the equivalent command that you'll need to execute is `/bin/bash -c ionic run`, thus you'll need to change the following:

1. remove the leading `cd` from `currentDirectoryPath` (that's probably a typo from a copy+paste from terminal) and add a leading `/` to have an absolute path
2. change `arguments`to `@[@"-c",@"ionic",@"run"]`, as each argument to NSTask should represent an item of the array.

If you have problems with `/usr/bin/bash` due to some other tools not being found, you can try using `/bin/sh`.

**Update** As [Aditya Vaidyam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238099/aditya-vaidyam) pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30472718/1974224) you might also need to setup the environment variables (especially the `PATH` one), to simulate the same conditions as for the terminal. If you want to find out which environment variables are set, just run the `env`command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as described above I'm still having trouble. I'll set a bounty ;-)

Comment: Thanks for paying attention :-)  But even with only `@[@"run"]` as argument it will give `env: node: No such file or directory`. I guess is has something to di with the ionic installation

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same trouble running a Gulp with NSTask.

Comment: @Cristik i appreciate your responce; I am sure The argument passing; see if i run specific command on terminal e.g.. 'class-dump -H -o <dir_path> <mac-o_path>' it works and makes header files to the <dir_path>; but with NSTask i am doing the same with above code suggested. and it is giving error "/bin/sh: class-dump: No such file or directory".

Comment: how to do that? @Cristik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154218/discussion-between-vikram-singh-and-cristik).

Comment: @Cristik well I came to the solution by passing the command like this -> /usr/local/bin/class-dump -H -o %@ %@",<path_to_directory>, <path_to_binary>]

Answer (score 3):

On top of what Cristik suggested, you need to add to the [environment variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTask/environment) (i.e. PATH), the location of node.js, unless it's already in /usr/bin/ or so.