# Angular JS 2 can't be installed, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have tried setting up Angular 2 to experiment with on my VPS. The needed steps are here:

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

The first command is successful:

```
$ npm install -g tsd@^0.6.0
```

But the second step causes an error:

```
tsd install angular2 es6-promise rx rx-lite
```

"/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory" is the error I get. I have tried installing this in my project folder as root, but that also didn't had success. Does someone know why I get this error? The command doesn't exist, but why not?

Is there an easier way to install this? I have seen "**npm install angular2**", but I don't know how that works, that's why I tried the steps

Comment: How did you install node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to make a symbolic link to node:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26320915/2033574)

Comment: Alternatively: `apt-get install nodejs-legacy`.  Debian is a bit snooty about two packages providing the same binary.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped me a lot!

Comment: Also, @user3493168 , I think it would be even better if you used [nvm](http://nvm.sh) to manage your node versions.