# Unable to run nw.js application in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, node-webkit, nw.js

Myself created a node webkit helloworld application based on the tutorial given in [this link](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/getting-started-with-node-webkit-apps/). Also I tried to run the same in ubuntu OS using the command given in [this link](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-run-apps). But when I run the command `nw /home/myUsername/Documents/myNodeWebkitApps/helloWorld/myApp.nw` it throws the following results in terminal.

```
usage
  nw [udp] <options> <host> <port>

Default TCP protocol can be changed to UDP by ``udp'' argument.
UDP options
  currently none
TCP options
  -f               firewall mode, connection is initiated by netread.
                   Host specification is ignored and can be omited.
  -c               ignored. Transmission checksum is activated by
                   default.
  -C algorithm     use the specified algorithm for checksum. This
                   option also implies -c.
                   Supported algorithms (the first is default):
                       md5 none
general options
  -i <file>        read data from file instead of stdin.
  -b               print speed in b/s instead of B/s
  -h <n>           print `#' after each n KiB transferred (def. 10485.76).
  -H <n>           print `#' after each n MiB transferred (def. 10.24).
  -q               be quiet.
  -v               be verbose.
  -vv              be very verbose.
  -V               show version.
  -vV              show verbose version.
return values
  0                no errors.
  1                some error occured.
  2                checksum validation failed.
```

How can I run the same as given by first link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to run the hello world application with the help of [this link](http://frontendgods.com/hello-world-desktop-app-with-node-js/) and this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320901/cannot-install-nodejs-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory) like

1. install nw builder by command `npm install nw-builder -g`
2. If you got the error something like `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory` then as given in second link above do a symlink of node as `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`
3. Now we can run our application by the command `nwbuild -r ~/Desktop/webkit-example`

Comment: In addition to above steps, when I trying to packaging my application using `nwbuild -p linux -o ~/Desktop/output ~/Desktop/webkit-example`. So I put another new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892201/unable-to-build-nw-js-hello-world-application

Answer (score 1):

The output here did not come from `nw.js` but `netrw` which is installed on your machine. You can fix it by removing `netrw` from your machine or correcting the path to `nw.js`.