# Unable to build nw.js hello world application

Tags: linux, node.js, nw.js

Myself trying to build a hello world application for Linux using nw-builder. It runs when I execute the run command `nwbuild -r /path/to/myapp` but when i am trying to build it for linux version it gives the following error.

```
 { [Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nw-builder/cache/0.13.0-beta4/linux32/nw.pak']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nw-builder/cache/0.13.0-beta4/linux32/nw.pak',
  syscall: 'lstat' }
```

When I checking the path for directory in cache folder, instead of `nw.pk` file i found `nw_100_percent.pak` and `resources.pak` files.

How can i solve the same?
Also is it possible to avoid the downloading of nw.js each time when I run or build the application? I tried it with giving the version number but not succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the application is using the old version

```
nwbuild ./ -p linux64 /path/to/myapp -v v0.12.3
```

Comment: I had done the same. And working fine. But why can't it able to run with latest version?