# npm-adduser failing on entering npm account's credentials

Tags: node.js, npm

I had created an npm package using a different machine. I git cloned that package into a different machine and tried running `npm publish` and got the following error:

```
npm ERR! need auth auth and email required for publishing
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "publish"
npm ERR! cwd /home/tarun/me/github/ng-popover
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tarun/me/github/ng-popover/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I figured I would need to run `npm-adduser`. So, I ran it and entered my credentials of my npm account. Then I got the following error:

```
npm http PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/-/user/org.couchdb.user:tarun-dugar
npm http 400 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/user/org.couchdb.user:tarun-dugar
npm ERR! Error: ValidationError: child "password" fails because ["password" is required] : -/user/org.couchdb.user:tarun-dugar
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:272:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:148:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:896:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:847:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "adduser"
npm ERR! cwd /home/tarun/me/github/ng-popover
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tarun/me/github/ng-popover/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: if possible try to upgrade npm. You are using an old version. Or, try to rename the current .npmrc file to force a refresh. You can also try to change your password in npmjs.com.

Comment: Upgrading npm worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using an old version of `npm` (1.3.10). To solve this I upgraded npm using the tips from this link: [upgrade npm on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320901/cannot-install-nodejs-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory)

And finally adding a symlink as described in this link: [symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320901/cannot-install-nodejs-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Do you know how to do this stuck with an old version? Like, I am using npm from Unity Hub on my school's laptop and they don't want use to use it so they never upgrade it. It's like 1.2.something. Any idea on how to do it this way? Maybe go to firewalled replit and create a temporary repl to publish and then delete?