# TimeoutException: Asp.net Core 2.2 with react , requests timeout period of 50 seconds

Tags: reactjs, iis, asp.net-core, create-react-app

When I run the Project with the VS 2017 on IIS Server the Timeout Exception occurs

> TimeoutException: The create-react-app server did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 50 seconds.

My package.json File

```
{
  "name": "Invest_Me",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.12",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.6.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.8",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "reactstrap": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.3.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^4.1.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^4.1.12",
    "@storybook/addons": "^4.1.12",
    "@storybook/react": "^4.1.12",
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.50.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9009 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I have also try the solution of
[.UseKestrel(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48732873/5894166)

Program.cs

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseKestrel(o => { o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); });
```

but the error exist

Stacktrace

```
System.TimeoutException: The create-react-app server did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 50 seconds. Check the log output for error information.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

How to increase the timeout of the create-react-app server

> it work fine when i try to run `npm start` in ClientApp folder by cmd

Comment: I've tried your `package.json` but it works for me. My best guess is your `node_modules/` is broken. Could you please remove the `node_modules/` folder and perform `npm i`? If it doesn't work , try `npm run build` before starting the server.

Comment: `npm run build` the issue is resolved

Comment: For Googlers: I had the same issue, practically overnight. Intellisense frequently butchers my entire ClientApp build process so I attempted deleting the .vs-folder, which didn't work. Turns out that Visual Studio required an update, and running it + restart + clean and build resolved the issue for me. (VS2019 and .NET Core 3.1).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For setting the StartupTimeout of create-react-app

Add these Startup.cs `Configure` method

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
 });
```

Comment: I get a `The name 'TimeSpan' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: This is an old answer I am Working on ASP.Net 2.1 at that Time

Comment: I'm working on netCore 2.2 right now, with a ReactJS front

Comment: TimeSpan is in the System namespace. Do you Included It

Comment: Thanks, now works (using System;), sorry, I have been dealing with 10 minutes in .net (and 3 years in angular, react...)

Answer (score 2):

you can use system.TimeSpan.
But issue has not been resolved. Still getting below error message.
"TimeoutException: The create-react-app server did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 0 seconds. Check the log output for error information."

Solution :

You can use below link This will resolve the issue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

1. In a command prompt, switch to the ClientApp subdirectory, and launch the CRA development server:
   cd ClientApp
   npm start
2. Modify your ASP.NET Core app to use the external CRA server instance instead of launching one of its own. In your Startup class, replace the spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer invocation with the following:
   spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");
   Press F5

Answer (score 0):

**For MacOS Ventura:**

In Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac sometimes when you try to run React App on .net show this error:

> TimeoutException: The create-react-app server did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 120 seconds.
> Check the log output for error information.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices. Extensions.Util. TaskTimeoutExtensions. With Timeout (Task task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message)

If you have installed node.js with Homebrew or nvm only add in your terminal:

```
sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s "$(which npm)" /usr/bin/npm
```

I base myself on these post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26320915/8183226

[Problem verifying node installation in m1 pro mac while setting up Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71304259/problem-verifying-node-installation-in-m1-pro-mac-while-setting-up-visual-studio)