# Why can't Visual Studio fro Mac run node?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I've installed Visual Studio for Mac community 8.10.11 and created a new Project based on React + .net Core WebAPI. But If I try to run the app, I got

```
/Users/xxx/Projects/yyy/yyy/yyy.csproj(5,5): Warning MSB3073: The command "node --version" exited with code 127. (MSB3073) (yyy)
/Users/xxx/Projects/yyy/yyy/yyy.csproj(5,5): Warning MSB4181: The "Exec" task returned false but did not log an error. (MSB4181) (yyy)
/Users/xxx/Projects/yyy/yyy/yyy.csproj(5,5): Error: Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE. (yyy)
```

My bash knows `node` and the folder is also part of `echo $path`. How can I add it to VS?

Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac has a different PATH to the terminal due to how GUI apps run on macOS. Where is node installed? You should be able to use 'which node' to see. I have node installed in /usr/local/bin/node' which is found by VS Mac. So adding a symlink there to where you have node installed may solve the problem you are having.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue because I used homebrew to install Node.js.

According to the [Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#my-mac-apps-dont-find-homebrew-utilities) documentation:

> GUI apps on macOS don’t have Homebrew’s prefix in their `PATH` by default. If you’re on Mountain Lion or later, you can fix this by running `sudo launchctl config user path "$(brew --prefix)/bin:${PATH}"` and then rebooting, as documented in `man launchctl`. Note that this sets the launchctl `PATH` for *all users*.

If you installed node from elsewhere, you should be able to modify this command to include the path to wherever your node executable is:

```
sudo launchctl config user path "<path-to-bin-folder>:${PATH}"
```

Comment: Additionally, I'm using Node.js LTS: node@16 keg-only formula, and it needs to be symlinked to the PATH, e.g. via `brew link node@16`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Joshua answer, if you installed Node with Homebrew or Nvm

/usr/local/bin doesn't has node link.

Only add in your terminal:

```
sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s "$(which npm)" /usr/bin/npm
```

[React-request-timeout-period-of-50-seg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54850605/timeoutexception-asp-net-core-2-2-with-react-requests-timeout-period-of-50-se)