# (shell script file) pm2: command not found in crontab task

Tags: shell, cron, pm2, cron-task

my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash    
pm2 start server.js
```

my crontab task

```
* * * * * /home/ec2-user/abcd/test.sh > /home/ec2-user/cron.log 2>&1
```

What I got from the log:

```
home/ec2-user/abcd/test.sh: line 2: pm2: command not found
```

how to fix it?

Remark:

1.When I execute ./test.sh, it runs normally

2.which pm2 - shows

```
~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/pm2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be because of that `PATH` environment variable hasn't been set when the cron job is being executed and this is why your shell script can't find `pm2`. You have to enter the complete address of `pm2`.

Example if `pm2` is in `/usr/bin/`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/pm2 start server.js
```

Or you may want to just set `PATH` env before the command you want to execute in you shell script.

In normal, when you execute the program in you terminal, the environment variables are set properly. This is why you can run your shell script in your terminal without any problem.

Comment: after executing the above code - 
/usr/bin/pm2: No such file or directory

Comment: Enter ```whereis pm2```. And see where it is located. Then replace it with the address I used in the code.

Comment: /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/pm2 - but I got - /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Comment: ```/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/pm2 start server.js```

So it doesn't work ?

Comment: shows /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Comment: @JustFun2020 check it reference this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320901/cannot-install-nodejs-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory"

Comment: Thanks @VictorLee.
Your referenced link has a relevant discussion to solve a similar issue for me.
To solve the below error which @JustFun2020 is getting
 `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory `
We need to make a symlink which can be done with the below command
`sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node`
Here `"$(which node)"` will fetch the Node version for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the path command like mentioned in the other answer.

```linux
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin"
```

Next, locate the path to your server.js file and add the pm2 start command with the path.

```js
pm2 start /home/ec2-user/ .....your path to the file..... /server.js
```

Complete code:

```linux
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin"
pm2 start /home/ec2-user/ .....your path to the file..... /server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You could as well use the inbuilt cron feature of `pm2`, i had a similar issue with `pm2` and cron on my linux server.

You can achieve the same thing with pm2:

Here...

- To start cron job with `pm2`

```bash
pm2 start your-app-name --cron "* * * * *" --no-autorestart
```

- To stop a cron process with `pm2`

```bash
 pm2 restart your-app-name --cron-restart 0
```

all in the docs here: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies